# Jquery load() works for html but not for php page

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to load a php page in a div with Jquery. The following code works perfectly with a html page (Test.html) but not with a php page (Test.php with exactly the same code as Test.html): when I clik on the button nothing occurs. My php page loads correctly outside the Jquery code. I even tried to use a url instead of a relative link without any success.

```
$(function() {
     $('#Button').click(function() {
         $('#Div').load('Test.php');
     });
});
```

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Here is the code of Test.php :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

Test Test 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the test page?

Comment: Are you calling the file from an html file or a php file? And could you post the Test.php page?

Comment: I tried this on my system, all works as intended.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. After I received your answer I tried to run the page online and it works. So I guess it must be an issue with my "easyphp configuration", any idea what it could be? My php pages load correctly with the localhost address and the jquery code works with the html pages.

Comment: Ok I found the issue, for an unknown reason my Test.php wasn't created in the easyphp folder. I copy pasted it and it works now; Thanks for your time.